# CharacterEllipsis doesn't work inside ItemsControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, texttrimming

I'm trying to set `CharacterEllipsis` on text inside a `DataTemplate` of an `ItemsControl`.

```
<Window x:Class="CustomPanel.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomPanel;assembly="
Title="Window1" Height="400" Width="400">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       Margin="100,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
                  Grid.Column="0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

I've also tried setting width to the `ItemsControl`, `StackPanel`'s and the `TextBlock` itself.

Any Ideas?

### EDIT

To inhance that this is not an issue of the `Style` or the `StackPanel`, I removed both and it still doesn't work

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                       Margin="100,0,0,0"
                       Width="200"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"/>
</Grid>
```

### Clarification

This works perfectly when the text is too big but I want it to work when the window is getting resized to a smaller width too.

Comment: WOW! You're only now mentioning that crucial part of your problem??? After 4 people have spent half an hour trying to help you?

Comment: @Sheridan I'm sorry. I have a bit of a problem explaining my self sometimes :/

Comment: Actually, I've just tested that and that doesn't make a difference either... I'm having trouble *not* making it work... even *with* a `StackPanel` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

Comment: @Omribitan How is the Person class defined? How is the list defined, and where is it defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataTemplate won't pick the style from window since it does not lie in that scope. Move the style either inside **`DataTemplate.Resources`** Or **`Application.Resources`** so that it can be picked by TextBlock inside DataTemplate.

Second, you have wrapped TextBlock inside StackPanel which gives it infinite size to expand. So, ***remove Stackpanel which is wrapping TextBlock***.

Third, constraint width of ItemsControl or set MaxWidth as you feel like.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Width="30">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

UPDATE:

In case you want to make it work for re-size of window, ***instead of setting width, set max width on TextBlock***:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" MaxWidth="200"
                    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ItemsControl Margin="100,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"/>
```

Comment: yes,set style in DataTemplate.Resources Or Application.Resources. or set x:key

Comment: I've tried that and even removed to style and applied the text trimming directly but still no effect. Updated my post with the current code

Comment: The posted code definitely works for small sample I have tried. Do you see cropped text? Issue lies somewhere in your code.

Comment: See my clarification. Sorry for not being clear earlier

Comment: Updated an answer for re-size comment. See if that works now.

Comment: It does. Sorry for not being clear earlier. Thanks :)

Comment: You don't actually need to set any `Width` or `MaxWidth` properties to make this work if resizing the `Window` is constraining the `TextBlock.Width`.

Comment: @Sheridan - But OP wants it to work both ways. So, he have to constraint MaxWidth to make both work.

Comment: Ok, but my point (not just to the OP) is just that anything that constrains the `TextBlock.Width` will trigger the character ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

**add `x:Key` to the style and set TextBlock's Style like this:( Rohit Vats has said the reason)**

```
<Style x:Key="tb" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"></Setter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Width="90" Style="{DynamicResource tb}" Text="{Binding Name}"
               Margin="100,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

**and then remove stackpanel or set textblock's width.**

**result:**

[image]

**and my test code is :**

```
            Persons = new List<Person>();
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name="One\ntwo two\nThree Three Three\nfour four four four";
            Persons.Add(p);
```

**another result:(resize the window)**

[image]

**code:**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">

                <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource tb}" Text="{Binding Name}"
                       Margin="100,0,0,0"/>

        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: -1 Without an `x:Key` directive set, the `Style` will be applied implicitly to all `TextBlock`s within scope.

Comment: see my last comment to @RohitVats

Comment: So this infact does work when the text is too large but how can I make it work when the window is getting resized to a smaller width?

Comment: @Omribitan see my update. remove stackpanle and textblock's width, then textblock's size will changed by the window.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty bold statement and an untrue one at that. Without even copying your code into a new project, I can see why you have that problem. In order for the `CharacterEllipsis` to work, the `TextBlock` needs to have some constraint put on its `Width`... otherwise, how would WPF know when to start the character ellipsis effect?

One solution would be to set an exact `Width` on the `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="100,0,0,0" Width="200" />
```

Of course, that won't be convenient for many people, so an alternative would be to *not* use the `StackPanel` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` (or in the `DataTemplate`) because they will let the `TextBlock` grow infinitely.

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, you have three possible solutions because the `Style` is out of scope of the generated `DataTemplate` elements:

a) Move the `Style` into the `DataTemplate.Resources`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
        </Style>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="100,0,0,0"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

b) Add the `TextTrimming` property directly to the `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="100,0,0,0"/>
```

c) Set the `Style` on the `TextBlock` explicitly:

```
<Style x:Key="YourStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
</Style>

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource YourStyle}" Text="{Binding}" Margin="100,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: I didn't mean to state that it doesn't work, I meant it doesn't work for me. Also, as I said in my post I've tried that and it still didn't work. I've also removed the stackPanel as the `ItemsPanel` and it still doesn't affect

Comment: Ok, that's unusual... give me a moment to copy it to a new project to test.

Comment: It *does* work... perhaps *you* should try it in a new project... clearly you are either *not* following this correct advice, or you have additional elements that are interfering with the normal behaviour. I have tested it in a new project and can confirm that all three of these solutions *do* work. Make sure that you remove the `StackPanel`s as originally suggested.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear earlier. It does work when the text is too big but I'm looking for a way to crop the text when the window resizes to a smaller width ...

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Remove your stackpanel in your datatemplate:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The stackpanel took whatever space it wanted, and thus the trimming was not working.

**Long answer:**

Example of setting datacontext:

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:PersonsViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Simple vm:

```
public class PersonsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person> { new Person { Name = "Bjarne balblablalblalbal balbalbalballblalbla" }, new Person { Name = "Arne Belinda blblabllalbalblllablalbla Arne Belinda blblabllalbalblllablalbla Arne Belinda blblabllalbalblllablalbla Arne Belinda blblabllalbalblllablalbla Arne Belinda blblabllalbalblllablalbla" }, new Person { Name = "Turid" } };
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return persons; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, persons)) return;
            persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator] // No R#? Comment this line out
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Person class must also implement INotifyPropertyChanged to signal change of the property..

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == name) return;
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Cheers

Stian

Comment: Please see the edit and the comments on the rest of the answers. it doesn't work.

Comment: @Omribitan I was a bit slow on my post button here, phone rang and Rohit was faster. Anyways this works just fine here. Read his comments regarding the stackpanel. It won't wrap because it consumes all space avaliable. Are you sure you have content in your list? Does your list implement INotifyPropertyChanged or is it a DO?